# how to pass a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable with name "myPassword" in function jquery but variable value in function return null.how to correct this?!

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var myPassword = $('#facebox #myPassword:first').val();
    $(myPassword).strength({
        strengthClass: 'strength',
        strengthMeterClass: 'strength_meter',
        strengthButtonClass: 'button_strength',
        strengthButtonText: 'Show Password',
        strengthButtonTextToggle: 'Hide Password'
    });
});
```

Comment: which plugin you are using for password strength

Comment: strength.js  link:http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Password-Input-Enhancement-Strength-js.html

Comment: Can you post your html?! NOTE: `:first` (in line 2) is unneccessary because `myParrword` is a id and ids should only exist one time in the whole page.

Comment: "variable value in function return null" — What function? What variable? Where are you returning from and to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it just the selector thats wrong (i.e. prepend with "."+ or "#" before)?

```
 var myPassword = $('#facebox #myPassword:first').val();
 $("." + myPassword).strength({ ...
```

Comment: myPassword should be a valid jQuery selector. For instance <div class="myDiv"/> is fetched by $('.myDiv') or <div id="myDiv"/> is $('#myDiv') I was just wondering if your variable myPassword is a valid selector or not.